# Appcelerator Titanium Google Maps v2 Android APP crash (Ti.Map)

Tags: android, google-maps, titanium, appcelerator, android-maps-v2

im using Ti.Map module and all i achieve is an APP crash all the time.
Im just using the example code for the mapView and trying titanium SDK 3.1.1 and 3.1.3, but every time i emulate my app on android it crushes.

here you have my errors:

```
Titanium Command-Line Interface, CLI version 3.1.2, Titanium SDK version 3.1.3.GA
Copyright (c) 2012-2013, Appcelerator, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
Please report bugs to http://jira.appcelerator.org/
[ERROR][InputDispatcher(   62)] channel '4076e278 com.rotary.imrotarian/com.rotary.imrotarian.IamrotarianActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
[ERROR][InputDispatcher(   62)] channel '4076e278 com.rotary.imrotarian/com.rotary.imrotarian.IamrotarianActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
[ERROR][DefContainer(  434)] Couldn't copy file: /data/local/tmp/app.apk
[ERROR][installd(   35)] cannot open /data/secure/data/: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][installd(   35)] Couldn't openat cache: No such file or directory
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1109)] (KrollRuntimeThread) [695,695] APP PROXY: ti.modules.titanium.app.AppModule@4060f720
[ERROR][GTalkService(  212)] asyncFetch: no username
[ERROR][dalvikvm( 1109)] Could not find class 'ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.searchview.TiUISearchView', referenced from method ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.TiUITableView.processProperties
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1109)] (main) [312,4216] Sending event: exception on thread: main msg:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$string; Titanium 3.1.1,2013/06/15 16:10,f7592c1
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1109)] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$string
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1109)]   at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.b(Unknown Source)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1109)]   at com.google.android.gms.internal.d.a(Unknown Source)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1109)]   at com.google.android.gms.internal.d.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1109)]   at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1109)]   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:871)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1109)]   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1083)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1109)]   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1109)]   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1431)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1109)]   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:523)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1109)]   at org.appcelerator.titanium.TiBaseActivity.onStart(TiBaseActivity.java:997)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1109)]   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1129)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1109)]   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:3791)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1109)]   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1620)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1109)]   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1109)]   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1109)]   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1109)]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1109)]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1109)]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1109)]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1109)]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1109)]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1109)]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1109)]   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1109)] FATAL EXCEPTION: main
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1109)] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$string
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1109)]  at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.b(Unknown Source)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1109)]  at com.google.android.gms.internal.d.a(Unknown Source)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1109)]  at com.google.android.gms.internal.d.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1109)]  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1109)]  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:871)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1109)]  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1083)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1109)]  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1109)]  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1431)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1109)]  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:523)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1109)]  at org.appcelerator.titanium.TiBaseActivity.onStart(TiBaseActivity.java:997)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1109)]  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1129)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1109)]  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:3791)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1109)]  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1620)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1109)]  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1109)]  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1109)]  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1109)]  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1109)]  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1109)]  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1109)]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1109)]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1109)]  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1109)]  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1109)]  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
[ERROR][InputDispatcher(   62)] channel '40740b58 com.rotary.imrotarian/com.rotary.imrotarian.IamrotarianActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
[ERROR][InputDispatcher(   62)] channel '40740b58 com.rotary.imrotarian/com.rotary.imrotarian.IamrotarianActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1138)] (KrollRuntimeThread) [647,647] APP PROXY: ti.modules.titanium.app.AppModule@40607fc8
[ERROR][GTalkService(  212)] asyncFetch: no username
[ERROR][dalvikvm( 1138)] Could not find class 'ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.searchview.TiUISearchView', referenced from method ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.TiUITableView.processProperties
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1138)] (main) [306,4093] Sending event: exception on thread: main msg:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$string; Titanium 3.1.1,2013/06/15 16:10,f7592c1
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1138)] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$string
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1138)]   at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.b(Unknown Source)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1138)]   at com.google.android.gms.internal.d.a(Unknown Source)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1138)]   at com.google.android.gms.internal.d.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1138)]   at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1138)]   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:871)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1138)]   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1083)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1138)]   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1138)]   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1431)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1138)]   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:523)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1138)]   at org.appcelerator.titanium.TiBaseActivity.onStart(TiBaseActivity.java:997)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1138)]   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1129)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1138)]   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:3791)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1138)]   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1620)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1138)]   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1138)]   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1138)]   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1138)]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1138)]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1138)]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1138)]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1138)]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1138)]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1138)]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1138)]   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1138)] FATAL EXCEPTION: main
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1138)] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$string
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1138)]  at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.b(Unknown Source)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1138)]  at com.google.android.gms.internal.d.a(Unknown Source)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1138)]  at com.google.android.gms.internal.d.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1138)]  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1138)]  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:871)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1138)]  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1083)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1138)]  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1138)]  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1431)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1138)]  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:523)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1138)]  at org.appcelerator.titanium.TiBaseActivity.onStart(TiBaseActivity.java:997)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1138)]  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1129)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1138)]  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:3791)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1138)]  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1620)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1138)]  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1138)]  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1138)]  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1138)]  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1138)]  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1138)]  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1138)]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1138)]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1138)]  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1138)]  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1138)]  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1179)] (KrollRuntimeThread) [762,762] APP PROXY: ti.modules.titanium.app.AppModule@4060a4c8
[ERROR][GTalkService(  212)] asyncFetch: no username
[ERROR][dalvikvm( 1179)] Could not find class 'ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.searchview.TiUISearchView', referenced from method ti.modules.titanium.ui.widget.TiUITableView.processProperties
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1179)] (main) [595,7794] Sending event: exception on thread: main msg:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$string; Titanium 3.1.1,2013/06/15 16:10,f7592c1
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1179)] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$string
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1179)]   at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.b(Unknown Source)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1179)]   at com.google.android.gms.internal.d.a(Unknown Source)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1179)]   at com.google.android.gms.internal.d.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1179)]   at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1179)]   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:871)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1179)]   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1083)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1179)]   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1179)]   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1431)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1179)]   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:523)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1179)]   at org.appcelerator.titanium.TiBaseActivity.onStart(TiBaseActivity.java:997)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1179)]   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1129)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1179)]   at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:3791)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1179)]   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1620)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1179)]   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1179)]   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1179)]   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1179)]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1179)]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1179)]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1179)]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1179)]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1179)]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1179)]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
[ERROR][TiApplication( 1179)]   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1179)] FATAL EXCEPTION: main
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1179)] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$string
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1179)]  at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.b(Unknown Source)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1179)]  at com.google.android.gms.internal.d.a(Unknown Source)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1179)]  at com.google.android.gms.internal.d.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1179)]  at com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1179)]  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:871)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1179)]  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1083)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1179)]  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1179)]  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1431)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1179)]  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:523)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1179)]  at org.appcelerator.titanium.TiBaseActivity.onStart(TiBaseActivity.java:997)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1179)]  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1129)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1179)]  at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:3791)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1179)]  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1620)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1179)]  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1179)]  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1179)]  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1179)]  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1179)]  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1179)]  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1179)]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1179)]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1179)]  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1179)]  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
[ERROR][AndroidRuntime( 1179)]  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I've tried to use Ti.Map 2.1.2 / 2.1.1 / 2.1.0 but the app crashes with all of them.
I've inserted the code in the tiApp.info for the manifest and i've added the google api key.

Hope you could help me.

Thx

Comment: I have the exact same problem, I have tested the maps with a Samsung galaxy s4 and my application crashes, but if I use a Samsung galaxy s3 or a Google nexus 4 my application does not crash, have you tried to change the Android version of the emulator?

Comment: I've fixed, the problem was that i was using the emulator, it really works, but not in the emulator, only in the device. Android things o_O